# How can I send only what is shown in the artboard of illustrator to be printed in cutting master 3 and not all the hidden details?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I downloaded a free SVG file online of a tuxedo and I am trying to print the outlets of it but illustrator is sending every little detail... I want to get rid of these? I have attached a sample picture of the "details" in the hankerchief  every little element is sent to the printer[image]

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you're saying. Are you saying that there are some sort of artifacts in the print that were not visible in Illustrator?

Comment: If they’re visible on the artboard, of course they’re going to be sent off to the printer when you print. Why wouldn’t they be? Doesn’t matter how big or small they are. I don’t understand what you’re asking either.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using this for some kind of plotter/cutter, such as for vinyl cutting, and don't want the overlapping shapes.  Your question is a bit hard to follow, so this is a guess.

Select everything - click Object > Path > Outline Stroke.

Open the pathfinder, and with everything still selected hit the Merge button.

[image]

All the shapes and strokes and fills will be turned into vectors with no overlaps, and no strokes.  If you ungroup the resultant vectors, you will see you can separate all the parts, and there are no overlaps.

[image]